# Can I host html5shiv and respond.js on a cdn?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to host html5shiv and respond.js from a cdn or do I have to call them locally?

currently I have integrated html5shiv and respond.js from cdn and selectivizr locally, I can leave everything as it is or I have to host them locally ^

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The benefit of cdn versions is user may already have them cached before they even venture to your site. Question is opinion based and therefore off-topic as outlined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to know if html5shiv and respond.js worked without any problems if they are hosted by cdn